# C: how to store input with possible mixed types at one position

Tags: c, arrays

Is there a method in C that, using arrays or structure, to store an a fixed -length/number of elements input while certain elements in this input can have multiple input types?

for instance, a 5-element array to store an input like: xxx-xx, which the first 3 elements can only be integers while the last 2 elements can be either integers or single characters (so input like 12300 or 123XX are both valid inputs)

Comment: With a `union`?

Comment: Will the first three elements be single-digit integers?  If so, then you hardly need anything more complex than a character array (probably, but not necessarily, a string), and you validate that the the first three characters are all digits and the last two are alphanumeric.  If you have more complex requirements, then a union is probably necessary, as suggested.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler so if I only input integers between 0 and 9, I can use a character array to store both single letters and these integers? when validating, I can just do `array[i] == 5` or `array[i] == 'x'`?